# Load pop up gallery inside Magnific Poup

Tags: jquery, image-gallery, magnific-popup

I have a page, say Albums, and only cover page I am showing here, each coverpage linked to a single page containing multiple images for that album, I am using magnific popup to show images in gallery in single pages, and working as indented.

So what I want to achieve is, when I click On the album cover images, I want to open the image gallery with the content of that albums single page(now it will redirect to single page), I know we have to do this via Ajax, and I can load all images in side a popup, But is there a way to make the popup behave like what we get in side the single page, that like per image in popup and next and Prev buttons.

I am using this code now: 
Here '.ajax-popup-link' is the link on each images in the Albums page, and `#gallery` is the wrapper div in the Single page

```
<li class="item">
   <div class="item_body">                             
               <a href="http://localhost/mysite/albums/test-album/" class="ajax-popup-link">
                <img src="http://localhost/mysite/uploads/starlight.jpg" /> </a>                    
    </div>
</li>
```

Here is the Single page Code

```
<ul class="gallery popup-gallery" id="gallery">
    <li class="item">
        <div class="item_body">          
                    <a class="" href="http://localhost/robanks/uploads/starlight_10.jpg">
                        <img src="http://localhost/mysite/uploads/2015/11/starlight.jpg" />                              
                    </a>              
        </div>
     </li>
</ul>

jQuery('.ajax-popup-link').magnificPopup({
    type: 'ajax',
    modal: true,
    gallery: {
        enabled: true,
        navigateByImgClick: true,
        preload: [0,1] // Will preload 0 - before current, and 1 after the current image
    },
            image: {
        tError: '<a href="%url%">The image #%curr%</a> could not be loaded.',
        titleSrc: function(item) {
          return item.el.attr('title');
        }
     },
    callbacks: {
    parseAjax: function(mfpResponse) {
            mfpResponse.data = jQuery(mfpResponse.data).find('#gallery .item');
            console.log('Ajax content loaded:', mfpResponse);
        },
        ajaxContentAdded: function() {
        $('#gallery').magnificPopup({
                        delegate: '.item a',
                        type: 'image',
                        tLoading: 'Loading image #%curr%...',
                        mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
                        gallery: {
                           enabled: true
                        }
                });
            console.log(this.content);
        }
    }
});
```

Any help will be appreciated.